# Haskell Instance of Num issue

Tags: string, haskell, int, concatenation

What is wrong with this code?

```
rectangle :: Int -> Int -> String
rectangle i j
    | i < 0 || j < 0    = ""
    | otherwise         = concatenate(i) ++ "n/" ++ (rectangle i) j-1




concatenate :: Int -> String
concatenate i
    | i <= 0            = ""
    | otherwise         = "*" ++ concatenate(i-1)
```

This is the error I get

```
  ERROR line 3 - Instance of Num [Char] required for definition of rectangle
```

This is supposed to be what it does (for example)

```
Main> putStr (rectangle 3 4)
****
****
****
```

Comment: @Ingo Sorry, just noticed and fixed it, however same error occurs

Comment: Without the second argument to rectangle, you're doing `String ++ (Int -> String)`

Comment: "But if I put this on the prompt it will say Not in scope 'n'." Say `let factor n = ` etc instead. The GHCi prompt acts like it's in a really big `do` statement (without the `do`).

Comment: "But in Haskell, as variables are immutable, how would I do the something++ thing?" You carry the world state, including the variables, around. The old state is part of the input, the new state is part of the output. You can do this manually with functions typed `doSomething :: s -> a -> (s, b)`, or have it carried around for you in a state monad, making the type `doSomethingM :: (MonadState s m) => a -> m b.`

Comment: @Rhymoid Hi, is there anyway that you could help with these problems by email or something? This is another question - Define a function swapwords that takes three String values w1, w2 and s, and returns s with all occurrences of the String w1, in the String s, replaced by the String w2, e.g. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2964960: I rolled back your question to [the version you'd asked originally](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20452785/1); the answers you got were for that question, and made no sense with the complete change.  [The newer question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20452785/2) was a perfectly fine Stack Overflow question, but it should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: @user2964960 I just rolled back your question to the original version.  The latest question made no sense with the provided answers.  Please create new questions for new questions rather than changing old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work.

```
rectangle :: Int -> Int -> String
rectangle i j
    | i < 0 || j < 0    = ""
    | otherwise         = concatenate i ++ "\n" ++ rectangle i (j-1)




concatenate :: Int -> String
concatenate i
    | i <= 0            = ""
    | otherwise         = "*" ++ concatenate (i-1)
```

Few comments on that:

```
concatenate(i) ==> concatenate i
-- You don't need to put parameters in brackets in haskell.
(rectangle i) j-1 ==> rectangle i (j-1)
-- See Ingo's explanation
"n/" ==> "\n"
-- That should be obvious
```

Comment: @Ingo @zudov Thank you very much, just a random question I have the following question however have no idea how to do it. Do you have any idea on this? Thanks!                                                Define a function flagpattern that takes a positive Int value greater than or equal to five and returns a String that can be displayed as the following `flag' pattern of dimension n, e.g.

Main> putStr (flagpattern 7)
*******
**   **
* * * *
*  *  *
* * * *
**   **
*******

Answer (score 3):

You will get used to Haskell syntax sooner or later. This here

```
(rectangle i) j-1
```

is parsed as

```
(rectangle i j) - 1
```

But you really want:

```
rectangle i (j-1)
```